# CamScanner A4 vs Letter pdf?

Tags: applications, document-scanner

After I scan a document with the app CamScanner, how do I export it to a letter-sized pdf? When I share to my dropbox as pdf, it uses A4 dimensions and I can't figure out where the setting for this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clumsy to find this setting but you need to add a page to the existing document. On the 3 dots menu you will find PDF settings → PDF page size with options as below. These settings are remembered for all documents, so you would need to change it if you want a diffrent size

[image]
[image]